# Is there any way to read information stored in binary (.bin) file?

Tags: binaryreader

I have a binary (.bin) file, I have opened it on Olly dB but wanted to read it but failed. please help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I do not know, actually I am using an accounting software, expiration date of that software is stored on that .bin file and I want to read or access that file so please help me out...

Comment: This site is for computer programming questions.

Comment: does binary file not relate to any programming language?

Comment: What programming language are you using to read the binary file? The answer will be different depending on the language. For example, for perl, it would be `open(I, "file.bin"); binmode(I); undef $/; $file = <I>;`. Or, if you're willing to use `Path::Tiny`: `use Path::Tiny; $file = path("file.bin")->slurp;`